# Como usar meu site ASP(via Script) para fazer upload de um txt que está em outro servidor por endereço FTP?

Tags: upload, asp, ftp

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer um script asp para fazer upload usando meu site em asp de um arquivo txt por um endereço ftp de outro servidor qualquer?

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar uma ideia, pode ser que funcione:

Use um `HTTP.Request` para ler o arquivo .txt e salve-o via `FSO` em seu site. Em seguida use um componente de upload disponível em seu servidor para enviar o arquivo .txt gerado.

Tudo isso (os scripts) vc acha fácil pesquisando e configurando de acordo com seu FTP.

Comment: Vou tentar e te digo David, valeu por enquanto